# How to fix RUBYOPT error: C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -C (RuntimeError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie in Rails, I want to use React as my front-end (Rails+React as a one app), so when I tried to install Webpack using this command:
´rails javascript:install:webpack´

I got this error:
´C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -C (RuntimeError)´

I'm using:

- Windows 11 Pro version 22H2
- Ruby 3.2.2
- Rails 7.0.5

I tried the following fixes and none of them worked:

- Manually added RUBYOPT environment variable with a value of ´-wo´ (I don't have a RUBYOPT in my environment variables, I have a ´Path´ variable with a value of ´C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\´).
- Re-installed Ruby to version (3.2.2).
- Re-intsalled Rails and updated the bundler and all gems.
- Updated Node.js to the latest version (v20.2.0).

Comment: What is `RUBYOPT` set to when running that command? Does the output of `gem env` look good?

Comment: It has en empty value, I tried adding it manually in advanced system settings>environment variables, and didn't work, tried literally everything from reinstalling, googling, chatGPT.. etc nothing seems to work and I even couldn't find anyone with the same problem

Comment: Does the same thing happen with `bin/rails`? Each Rails install has a "binstub" that can help with weird issues in the system-installed Rails.

Comment: Nothing happens with bin/rails, it just won't execute without returning any errors